# How do you analyse the rank of a matrix depending on a parameter

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

I have the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3-t & 3 & 2t \\
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 2+t \\
t+2 & 0 &t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And I'm asked to evaluate the matrix's rank depending of $t$, using the determinants and minors of the matrix. However, the solution I see in the answer book is too short and only addresses one minor
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3-t & 3 & 2t \\
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 2+t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and its determinant equals $0$. But I've tried different minors and they dont give always the same answer. Is it because I'm doing it wrong or I should think of something else?

The answer book is [this](https://solucionarios10.com/wp-content/uploads/Matematicas-II-Anaya-2oBACH-tema-2-Determinantes.pdf) page 85 ex 30

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The determinant of this minor doesn't equal $0$ but $-3 - 12t + (9 - 3t) + (12 + 6t) = -9t + 18$.

Comment: Use the Gauss algorithm. You don't need to split it into minors.

Comment: Row operations...

Answer (score 2):

The given matrix is $4\times 3$, hence there are four $3\times 3$ minors.
What you should know from [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Determinantal_rank_%E2%80%93_size_of_largest_non-vanishing_minorhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Determinantal_rank_%E2%80%93_size_of_largest_non-vanishing_minor) is that if all determinants of such minors are zero then the rank of the given matrix is less than 3, otherwise it is exactly $3$.
Personally, I would start from the minor obtained by removing the first row whose determinant is very easy to compute:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 2+t \\
t+2 & 0 &t
\end{pmatrix} \implies \det \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 2+t \\
t+2 & 0 &t
\end{pmatrix}=3(-2t+t+2)=3(-t+2).$$
So if $t\not=2$ then the rank is $3$, otherwise the rank is $\leq 2$. Plugging $t=2$ into the matrix we find
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 \\
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 0 &2
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Are you able to find at least one $2\times 2$ minor (their number is 18) whose determinant is not zero? In that case the rank of the matrix is $2$ otherwise it is $1$.

Comment: Silly me, you are perfectly right! Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rank-nullity
$$\begin{align}\ker(M) &= \{\vec v|M\vec v = 0\} \\
&= \left\{\vec v|\begin{pmatrix}
3-t & 3 & 2t \\
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 2+t \\
t+2 & 0 &t
\end{pmatrix}\vec v = 0\right\} \\
&= \left\{\vec v|\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3/5 & 3t/5 \\
0 & 1 & t-5/6 \\
0 & 0 & 2-t \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\vec v = 0\right\}\\
&= \begin{cases}
\lambda\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{7}{6} \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} & \text{if $t=2$}\\
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

So: $$\operatorname{nullity}(M) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $t=2$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and $$\begin{align}\operatorname{rank}(M) &= \dim(\operatorname{dom}(M))-\operatorname{nullity}(M)\\
&=\begin{cases} 2 & \text{if $t=2$}\\
3 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The worst part of the question  is to change the matrix into echelon form. Did you use computer? You didn't show the steps. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

By row operations,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3-t & 3 & 2t \\
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 3 & 2+t \\
t+2 & 0 &t
\end{pmatrix}\sim$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3t-6 & t^2+t-6 \\
0 & 6 & 3+2t \\
1 & 3 & 2+t \\
0 & -3t-6 &-t^2-3t-4
\end{pmatrix}\sim$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac32 t-3 \\
0 & 6 & 3+2t \\
1 & 3 & 2+t \\
0 & 0 &\frac12 t-1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now it is obvious that when $t=2$, the rank of the matrix is $2$ and otherwise rank is $3$.

Answer (score 1):

**The rest is (much) easier, requiring almost no calculation and no algebra.**

Stare at this part of the matrix, which consists of the constant entries independent of $t:$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 & 3 &   \\
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
1  & 3 &   \\
  & 0  
\end{pmatrix}$$

**By inspection,**

- The always nonzero middle column shows the rank is at least 1.
- The coefficients on the second row then show the rank cannot be 1 (and therefore is at least 2), because neither the first nor the third columns can be nonzero multiples of the second column.
- The rank cannot exceed 3, the smaller of the numbers of rows and columns.

**Equivalently,** because you are asked to use determinants and minors, notice that the $(2,3)\times(1,2)$ minor,

$$\pmatrix{-2 & 0 \\ 1 & 3},$$

has nonzero determinant, whence the rank is always at least 2.  Possibly the answer presumed you would notice this in due course (it's the only $2\times 2$ minor not explicitly depending on $t$) and that this doesn't involve any algebra to work through.

Consequently, **the question comes down to characterizing the values of $t$ that reduce the rank of the matrix from its maximum of 3 to 2.**  The answer can be construed as finding *some* values of $t$ that definitely make the rank equal to 3.

*The answer therefore is deficient insofar as it's conceivable that when the upper $3\times 3$ minor is of reduced rank, adjoining the bottom row increases the rank.*  This, I believe, is the motivation for your question, and it's legitimate.  But the answer at least found that only $t=2$ can possibly reduce the rank.  And indeed, plugging in that value yields a matrix with identical first and third rows, $(1,3,4),$ and whose fourth row $(4,0,2)$ is $-2$ times the second row, $(-2,0,-1):$ obviously of rank 2, *QED.*